# How to access a controller method from a jbuilder template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I call a method on controller A that renders a jbuilder template (a file called signed_in.json.jbuilder). Inside the template I want to call a method, friendsCount, that is in controller B. I'm getting an error when I try to access the controller B method inside the template. The error is:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `friendsCount' for #<#<Class:0x007f90a09994f8>:0x007f90a0998788>:
  app/views/api/sessions/signed_in.json.jbuilder
```

I thought that adding `helper_method: friendsCount` to controller B should solve exactly the type of issue I want to solve: making a controller method available in views.
Actually, when I try to access a method from my ApplicationsController in my jbuilder template (controller C below), I have no issue. 
Here is my code:

CONTROLLER A:

```
class Api::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_credentials(session_params[:username], session_params[:password])
    if @user.nil?
      render json: ["couldn't find user"], status: 404
    else
      sign_in!(@user)
      render :signed_in
    end
  end

  private
  def session_params
    params.require(:session).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

JBUILDER TEMPLATE: signed_in.json.jbuilder

```
json.friendsSorted sortFriends
json.friends friendsCount
```

CONTROLLER B

```
class Api::FeedsourcesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :friendsCount

  def friendsCount
    friendsCountHash = {}
    # ... populate friendsCountHash

    render json: friendsCountHash
  end
```

CONTROLLER C

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :sortFriends

  def sortFriends
    #...
    return sortedFriendsArray
  end
end
```

I do not want to have the friendsCount method in the helpers folder because I also need to be able to have a direct controller route to this method for other purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have helper methods in the calling controller or its superclass.

In your case it's `SessionsController` and `ApplicationController`.

`FeedsourcesController` is not superclass for `SessionsController`, so view renderer do not know about any methods in it.

Comment: Okay, so I'll just put it in my application controller. Is there any reason why there is no way to access another controller? I would imagine it's because it's potentially dangerous somehow, but why is would it be more dangerous than calling another method in the calling controller or it's superclass?

Comment: If keep things simple - any view is rendered in the context of controller instance (in reality that is a bit complex, that is why you should declare helper methods)